# PHP PDO_Informix Locale Error -23101

Tags: php, pdo, informix

> SQLSTATE=HY000, SQLDriverConnect: -23101 [Informix][Informix ODBC Driver][Informix]Unspecified System Error = -23101

OS: Ubuntu 16.04 64Bits

- Install Informix CSDK (Version 4.10)
- Compile PDO_INFORMIX (Version 1.3.3)
- Enable pdo_informix.so extension in apache config
- Set apache environment variables

  1 - INFORMIXDIR = /opt/informix (where I installed CSDK)

  2 - DB_LOCALE = en_US.819

  3 - CLIENT_LOCALE = en_US.utf8

Connection String: `$instance = new PDO("informix:host=$host;service=$port;database=$db;server=ol_standard;protocol=onsoctcp;client_locale=en_US.utf8;db_locale=en_US.819;EnableScrollableCursors=1;OPTIMIZEAUTOCOMMIT=1", $usr, $pwd);`

The 23101 error is about DB_LOCALE and CLIENT_LOCALE, but it is all set.

Comment: yeah, 23101 is definitely about not finding GLS files. Are you sure INFORMIXDIR is correctly set?. Something you can try is to set the environment variable "GLSDEBUG" to "on" (e.g. export GLSDEBUG=on)  and check the output running the script. It should trace all the GLS calls, showing which file is failing to open.

Comment: You use OPTIMIZEAUTOCOMMIT in all caps.  Are you sure you're allowed to use `db_locale` and not required to use `DB_LOCALE`?  Ditto `client_locale` and `CLIENT_LOCALE`?

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the text in the error message, I think you have more than just a locale problem (23101).

If you get:   "**Unspecified System Error**"

rather that:  "**Unable to load locale categories**"

it means the driver was unable to find the correct text message for the -23101 error, which usually happens when INFORMIXDIR is not correctly set.

The '.iem' files (in $INFORMIXDIR/msg/en_us/0333) contains the text message for each error number. If a message can't be found you get a generic 'Unspecified System Error'.

You mentioned Apache, so I guess you are trying to run a PHP code from apache, not just the command line. Apache may not be passing the env variable to the PHP module.
If the apache env module (mod_env.so) is enabled, you may want to try putting something like this in your httpd.conf file

```
 setenv INFORMIXDIR '/opt/informix'
```

so the INFORMIDIR variable will be passed to the PDO module.

Comment: J_S, INFORMIXDIR is set like you said (setenv INFORMIXDIX 'opt/informix' in my apache2.conf. The mod_env module is enabled. The code error -23101 is about locale problem.

Comment: 23101 is "unable to load locale categories", but you are getting "unspecified system error" instead, and that only happens when the function in charge of loading the message for a specific error can't find the message files. And that happens when INFORMIXDIR is not set.  You can try doing a truss (strace) of the httpd process and checking from where is trying to load the iem / lc (locale) files.

Comment: quick note, 23101 may also appear if the user running Apache (usually 'www-data') has no access to the $INFORMIXDIR dir. The environment variables may be correctly passed to the PDO module, but if the user can't get the stuff inside INFORMIXDIR, it will fail.

Comment: thanks to jsagrera - strace revealed the following: `openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/informix/gls/cm3/registry", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory) `.  The system tried to load from a wrong path even though INFORMIXDIR has been set to lead somewhere else.